# Lightning Datatable selected-rows not working when data comes from wire

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, lwc-wire-adapter

When getting data via wire method, selected-rows does not work, even when hard coding a record id to be passed to it. See below:

myDataTableCmp.js:

```js
    import { LightningElement, wire } from "lwc";
    import getContacts from "@salesforce/apex/MyDataTableCtrl.getContacts";
    
    const columns = [
      { label: "Contact name", fieldName: "Name", type: "text" },
      { label: "Contact email", fieldName: "Email", type: "text" }
    ];
    
    export default class MyDataTable extends LightningElement {
      columns = columns;
      contacts = [];
    
      preselectedContactRow = ["0035w00003oJ5KQAA0"];
    
      @wire(getContacts)
      wiredContacts(result) {
        if (result.data) {
          this.contacts = result.data;
        }
      }
    }
```

myDataTableCmp.html:

```html
    <template>
      <div class="slds-p-horizontal_small">
        <lightning-datatable
          key-field="id"
          columns={columns}
          data={contacts}
          selected-rows={preselectedContactRow}
        >
        </lightning-datatable>
      </div>
    </template>
```

However, if I hard code the data (instead of querying it) and not use wire, it works (and selects the row):

```js
    import { LightningElement, wire } from "lwc";
    
    const columns = [
      { label: "Contact name", fieldName: "Name", type: "text" },
      { label: "Contact email", fieldName: "Email", type: "text" }
    ];
    
    const contacts = [
      {
        id: "0065w00002BRfvJAAT",
        Name: "Roy Goodman",
        Email: "roy@roy.com"
      },
      {
        id: "0065w00002BRupJAAT",
        Name: "Tracy Smith",
        Email: "tracy@tracy.com"
      }
    ];
    
    export default class MyDataTable extends LightningElement {
      columns = columns;
      contacts = contacts;
      preselectedContactRow = ["0065w00002BRfvJAAT"];
    }
```

How can I get it to select the row when using wire method to get the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `contacts` is setted in a wired function, it is not available in the first rendering cycle, so the datatable receives an invalid array of selected rows, therefore ignored.
Once the wired function returns its data and set `contacts`, just the `data` property of the datatable is updadated, `preselectedContactRow` doesn't change, so the standard component doesn't run the method to automatically select some rows.

To fix this issue you should render the datatable only when `contacts` hold some values:

```html
<template>
    <div class="slds-p-horizontal_small" lwc:if={contacts.length}>
        <lightning-datatable
            key-field="Id"
            columns={columns}
            data={contacts}
            selected-rows={preselectedContactRow}>
        </lightning-datatable>
    </div>
</template>
```

Please prefer [`lwc:if`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_conditional) directive over `if:true` since the latter is no longer recommended because Salesforce intends to deprecate it.

By the way, the `key-field` attribute should be `Id` since Javascript is case-sensitive.

When you hardcode `contacts`, those data are available since the first rendering cycle, so everything works fine.

Comment: Still not working, after applying that change. What could it be you think?

Comment: Does `getContacts` return a list of SObject (Contact)? If so, the `key-field` attribute should be `Id` since Javascript is case sensitive

Comment: Ah, that was it. Working now, thanks!